# Can someone explain why my .propagate(False) is not working?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

My other uses of `.propagate(False)` to stop my Frame from shrinking to match the size of the widgets works fine, but for some reason it's not working here.

I've tried different orders and using .pack vs .grid and I can't get it to work for some reason.

```
from tkinter import *

screen_width=1920
screen_height=1080
value=4

root = Tk()

common_product_frame = Frame(root, width=1000, height=800,highlightbackground='grey', highlightcolor='grey', highlightthickness=5)
common_product_frame.pack()
common_product_frame.propagate(False)    

text1_button = Button(common_product_frame, width=15, height=value, text="Text1", font="Tahoma 14 bold")
text1_button.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=10, pady=10)

text2_button = Button(common_product_frame, width=15, height=value, text="Text2", font="Tahoma 14 bold")
text2_button.grid(column=0, row=1, padx=10, pady=10)

root.mainloop()
```

I expected the frame to stay at the 1000, 800 size but it shrank around the two buttons.

Anyone know why?

Comment: Please always use the generic [python] tag for all python questions

Answer (score 1):

It is not working because `propagate` is an alias for `pack_propagate` but you are using `grid` to lay out the widgets inside the frame. `pack_propagate` only works when slaves are managed by `pack`.

Since you are using `grid`, you need to use `grid_propagate`. That, or switch to using `pack` instead of `grid` to layout the buttons.

Comment: I've switched it to pack because that's what my other frames have used, and it's not working. Change the .grid to .pack()
Any ideas?

Comment: @TBurnard: I don't know what you mean by "not working". When I use `pack` instead of `grid` in your code, the frame says the original requested size.

Comment: It's weird. I had a problem with the outline of my frame and then once I reloaded my problem it worked. Thanks for the help!